# start terminal from bootable USB drive

Tags: command-line, live-usb, live-cd, desktop-environments

I am running Ubuntu from a bootable USB drive on an old machine. The graphical interface is using up all the memory and I actually just need a terminal.

Is there a way to not start the desktop environment from a live OS image?

Answer (score 3):

When GRUB is loading, shortly after the BIOS finishes loading, quickly press `shift` or `esc`. This should allow you to boot the recovery mode.

Comment: I did as you said,  and it seemed to work for the first few seconds.  Too bad it quickly switched to graphical mode without my consent.  ;)

Answer (score 3):

### UEFI + Ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64

With a UEFI boot (without CSM enabled in firmware), the media boots into a GRUB menu.
<sub>UEFI booting can be troublesome, some firmware has the tendency to change from UEFI to BIOS boot in between reboots. Other times the USB stick needs to be plugged in a different port after each boot for the firmware to recognize it.</sub>

When you see a graphical (not text) Ubuntu boot screen it is likely that your firmware has enabled CSM and in effect disabled UEFI boot. Go back in your firmware and re-enable the (ultra) fast boot mode.

By default `*Try Ubuntu without installing` is selected in the GRUB menu.

1. Press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit this line.
2. Move your cursor to the `b` of `boot=casper`
   after `vmlinuz.efi`
   using the arrow keys <kbd>↓</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd>
3. Type (insert) the word `text` and a <kbd>space</kbd> there.
4. Press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

---

You might want to replace the existing `quiet splash` with `text` to get rid of the graphical splash screen and see the dmesg output on screen.

Comment: Wow, could you have made that less clear?

Answer (score 1):

As of today you must add the following option to the boot command:

```
systemd.unit=multi-user.target
```

In order to do so, hit F6, then Escape, then add this after the dashes